# BigQuery arrays - SELECT DISTINCT ordering guarantees?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to filter out the duplicates from a BigQuery array. I also need the order of the elements to be preserved. [The docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#filtering_arrays) mention that this can be done by combining `SELECT DISTINCT` with `UNNEST`. However, it doesn't mention any ordering behavior. I ran this query and got the desired ordering of `[5, 3, 1, 4, 10, 8]`.

```sql
WITH an_array AS (
  SELECT [5, 5, 3, 1, 4, 4, 10, 8, 5, 1] AS nums
)

SELECT
  ARRAY((
    SELECT DISTINCT num
    FROM UNNEST(nums) num
  ))
FROM an_array;
```

I don't know if that's coincidence or if that ordering is guaranteed. I also tried adding `WITH OFFSET` with an `ORDER BY` to specify the order explicitly, but in that case I get `Query error: ORDER BY clause expression references table alias offset which is not visible after SELECT DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always be explicit about ordering if you care about it:WITH an_array AS (

```
WITH an_array as (
  SELECT [5, 5, 3, 1, 4, 4, 10, 8, 5, 1] AS nums
)
SELECT ARRAY((SELECT num
              FROM UNNEST(nums) num WITH OFFSET o
              GROUP BY num
              ORDER BY MIN(o)
             )
            )
FROM an_array;
```